# How to use italics?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to use tkinter to make an app. I was able to follow a guide online how to make app that can change frames like a book.

I would like to be able to have italics in the text and also if possible, that the frames will be seamless instead of closing/reopening. Also, when I press next chapter, then previous chapter, and then again, it closes.

Note: I would like to have the "was" in verse two before upon the face of the waters to be italics not the whole sentence

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x10000")  # Set the window size
root.title("Authorized King James Bible")

# Create a label
l = tk.Label(root, text="Genesis 1")
l.config(font=("josefin_Sans", 14))
l.pack()

# Create a text widget
text = tk.Text(root, height=42, width=300)
text.pack()

# Define tags for formatting
text.tag_configure("italic", font=("josefin_Sans", 14, "italic"))
text.tag_configure("normal", font=("josefin_Sans", 14))  # Remove the bold attribute


# Genesis 1 Verses
Genesis_1 = """
1:1  ¶ IN the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
1:2  And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the waters.
1:3  And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.
1:4  And God saw the light, that """
text.insert(tk.END, Genesis_1)
text.insert(tk.END, "it was", "italic")  # Apply the \"italic\" tag
text.insert(tk.END, " good: and God divided the light from the darkness.", "normal")


def nextChapter():
    root.destroy()
    import Genesis2

tk.Button(
    root,
    text="Next Chapter",
    command=nextChapter
).pack(fill=tk.X, expand=False, side=tk.TOP)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
b2.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=False, side=tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please only focus on a single question.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of understanding, I've kept your first two lines of text  as it is. In the remaining lines, I have made the alternate lines bold and italic. Please follow.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1000")  # Set the window size
root.title("Authorized King James Bible")

# Create a label
l = tk.Label(root, text="Genesis 1")
l.config(font=("josefin_Sans", 14))
l.pack()

# Create a text widget
text = tk.Text(root, height=42, width=300)
text.pack()

text.tag_configure("italic", font=("josefin_Sans", 14, 'bold', "italic"))
text.tag_configure("normal", font=("josefin_Sans", 14))



# Genesis 1 Verses
Genesis_1 = '''1:1  ¶ IN the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.'
1:4  And God saw the light, that
'''
text.insert(tk.END, Genesis_1)
text.insert(tk.END, "\n1:2  And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the waters", "italic")
text.insert(tk.END, "\n1:3  And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.", "normal")
text.insert(tk.END, " \ngood: and God divided the light from the darkness.", "italic")


def nextChapter():
    root.destroy()
    import Genesis2

tk.Button(
    root,
    text="Next Chapter",
    command=nextChapter
).pack(fill=tk.X, expand=False, side=tk.TOP)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
b2.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=False, side=tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```